# Does Graph SDK work along side VSTO, COM Add-Ins or MS Office COM Interop?

Tags: vsto, office-addins, azure-ad-msal, com-interop, microsoft-graph-sdks

We have two projects; one's a VSTO Add-in and the other is a TypeLibrary which exposes Outlook COM Interop calls by registering the assembly as a set of COM interfaces.

This setup has allowed us to communicate with Office products (Excel, word, and Outlook) from our old C++ executable. This has been working fine for nearly 10 years.

We've tried adding some Graph API calls and we're getting the following exception:

**Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal.dll**

The graph api sdk calls I'm making work perfectly fine when in their own projects (e.g. .NET Core) as a class Library.  However, when I add that working class library project to my legacy projects, I get the problems above.

**Code Being Executed**

```
await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
```

Comment: Try to create a new class library targeting the same .net framework version and use Graph API from there. Do you get the same picture?

Comment: I'll try that and get back to you.  I know things worked with .Net Core; but the VSTO and Typelibrary I mentioned are using.Net Framework 4.8.   I'll get back to you ASAP

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev
I set up two simple projects.  One targeting .NET Core and the other .NET Framework 4.8
In each case the structure of the project was the same.  Two projects.  One an Executuable with a "Main" and the other a classlibrary with the Graph calls.   Included a reference to the classLibrary in the main project (the EXE); added a "Using" and boom.  No problems.  Successful API calls.

Comment: Does your main project use .net framework 4.8 as the target one as well?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev 
Yes

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev:

Correct me if I'm wrong, but VSTO and COM Add-Ins have a rule that everything must run in the same thread.   A graph API call using "GetAsync()" would definitely be spinning off another thread.   I'm wondering if that's the issue.   I think this would now disqualify my VSTO Add-In from using Graph API.

What remains is my TypeLibrary.  The one that was created to expose Outlook Interfaces by using COM Registration  (using regASM to register the assembly, and tlib to create the type library)